# Call a method from inside of subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, rxjs5

Im trying to call a method from inside of subscribe in angular/ionic. But its not working. Here is my code:

```
somemethod()
{
  const browser = this.iab.create('https://someurl.com');
  browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event=>{
    if(event.url === 'https://specificurl.com'){
      browser.close();
 // trying to call a member method from here , working
this.mymethod();
    }
  });
  browser.on('exit').subscribe(eventx=>{
   // trying to call a member method from here 
this.mymethod();
});
}
mymethod()
{
http.get<any>(url).subscribe(e=> { 
this.myvar = e.response; // this data is shown to user, but the user interface is not changing until something is clicked by the user
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case... You create the in app browser for url `https://someurl.com` but you subscribe and check for `https://specificurl.com`. What if you change it to listen for what you create?

```js
if(event.url == 'https://someurl.com'){
      console.log(event)
      browser.close();
    }
```

If the block itself is reachable go over the scope. Example:

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = TabsPage;
  response$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.myMethod();
    });
  }
  myMethod() {
    console.log('cool');
    // TODO supply valid url and other params if neccessary
    this.response$ = http.get<any>(url).pipe(data => {return data;})
  }
}
```

Then use `response$` like so:

```
<div>{{ response$ | async}}</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-p5qfps?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks, the block itself is being executed without issue, the browser.close() is working, but im unable to call any other method from the same block. i guess the problem is with the scope of class method.

Comment: Ah okay - so you can reach the block. I have edited my answer and added scope example.

Comment: ok, still my original question, now i observe that the method is being called, but output is not being generated till user takes some action on page, as soon as user clicks something, the output from method is being populated, very strange behaviour by angular.

Comment: Then post the problem of what is not being output? What is not being populated? What is strange? Right now your question was how to call `this.mymethod()`.

Comment: edited the question, please have a look

Comment: So now problem became that you want to know how to use Observables. I have added an example `this.response$ = http.get<any>(url).pipe(data => {return data;})`.

Comment: @Joosep.P What is the point of `.pipe(data => { return data; })`? Is it possible that it works just the same without it?

Comment: In short, we take return data whatever comes from url as an Observable, and place it in `this.response$`. It waits for something to return and then assigns it to the variable. Without that ending part nothing would happen. Now we have data as an Observable in `this.response$`. In template we use `| async` to take the data from `this.response$` and show the data to user in template with `{{ }}`. To use the data and manipulate it in TS file you would need to use `.subscribe(data => console.log(data))`.